# C code having trouble displaying the right time with a minute added to it

Tags: c

this is the ques i was suppose to code...ive done the code but its not displaying the final time properly...any help would be usefull
Write a program that prompts a user to enter the hour, minute, and either AM 
or PM. The program will add 1 minute to the time that has been entered, and 
display the new time. This program need only to ask for the time once.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>


   int main()
   {
    int mint, hour;
    char tod;

    printf("Enter the hour: ");
    scanf("%d", &hour);
    printf("Enter the minute: ");
    scanf("%d", &mint);
    printf("Enter AM or PM: ");
    getchar;
    scanf("%s", &tod);

    if(mint ==59){
        mint = 0;
    }
    if (hour == 12){
        hour = 1;
        if (tod='A'){
            tod = 'P';
        }
        else
            tod = 'A';
    }
    else
        mint = mint + 1;


 /*   if (hour < 11){
        if (mint < 59){
            mint = mint + 1;

    }
        else
            hour = hour + 1;
            mint = 0;
    }
    if (hour == 11 && mint == 59){
        hour = 12;
        mint = 0;
        if (tod[0]='A'){
            tod[0]='P';
        }
        else
            tod[0]='A';


  }
    if (hour == 12 && mint == 59){
        hour = 1;
        mint = 0;

    }*/
    printf("The new time is %d:%0d %c", hour, mint, tod);

  }
```

Comment: `char tod;` and `scanf("%s", &tod);`: if you use `scanf` you need an array of `char` not a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile, get into the good habit of adding the compiler flag `-Wall` to turn on all warnings, which will quickly show you the problem spots:

```
$ gcc -Wall test42.c
test42.c:23:19: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
           if (tod='A'){
               ~~~^~~~
test42.c:23:19: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
           if (tod='A'){
                  ^
               (      )
test42.c:23:19: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
           if (tod='A'){
                  ^
                  ==
test42.c:15:8: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
       getchar;
       ^~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
```

Take a look at the second note to the first warning.